# Extract Values from a Variable DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, indexing

I am attempting to pull data from a variable dataFrame (variable in terms of # of rows and columns as well as row/column titles), however I need to filter out only the specific values that I care about, ie the cells that are not zero.

For all cells that are not Zero, I need to extract the Ref Des (Row title), Voltage Number (column title), and Cell value; then export those values into a text file.

Currently I am able to pull the spreadsheet into a DataFrame, but I do not know how to index the array to extract only what I want from it.

```
df = pd.read_excel(ExcelFilename, sheet_name='Sheet1', sep='delimiter', header=5, index_col(0))
df.fillna('', inplace=true)
```

Output:
[This is the current dataFrame that I want to extract values from. Note: the dimensions of the array are variable and will change as well as the titles for Ref Des and Voltages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJmDX.png)

Comment: Pls post the requested output

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the trick here will be to set your "ref" column as the index. Then use `np.where` to extract the locations of where the non-zeros are happening. Once you have the locations, you can then extract their corresponding index/column values with simple indexing. Then to get the values you can use the `DataFrame.lookup` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ref": ["U{}".format(i) for i in range(11)],
    "random": np.random.rand(11),
    "voltage1": np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=11, p=[.8, .1, .1]),
    "voltage2": np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=11, p=[.8, .1, .1]),
    "voltage3": np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=11, p=[.8, .1, .1]),
    "voltage4": np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=11, p=[.8, .1, .1]),
})

df = df.set_index("ref")

print(df)
       random  voltage1  voltage2  voltage3  voltage4
ref                                                  
U0   0.592230         0         0         0         0
U1   0.896761         0         0         0         0
U2   0.406733         0         0         0         0
U3   0.552078         2         0         2         0
U4   0.271653         1         0         0         2
U5   0.455444         0         0         0         0
U6   0.401714         0         1         0         0
U7   0.248413         0         0         0         0
U8   0.505866         0         0         0         0
U9   0.310381         0         0         0         2
U10  0.373035         0         0         0         0
```

Now we filter to only include columns that have "voltage" in it. The from that we extract the integer positions of all non-zero items. We can use those integer positions to retrieve the dataframe index/column values, and lastly we can extract those corresponding values as well and put them all into one final output.

```
voltages_only = df.filter(like="voltage")
locations = np.where(voltages_only != 0)

indices = voltages_only.index[locations[0]]
columns = voltages_only.columns[locations[1]]
values = voltages_only.lookup(indices, columns)

out = pd.DataFrame({
    "ref": indices,
    "voltage": columns,
    "value": values,
})

print(out)
  ref   voltage  value
0  U3  voltage1      2
1  U3  voltage3      2
2  U4  voltage1      1
3  U4  voltage4      2
4  U6  voltage2      1
5  U9  voltage4      2
```